# Desenhar apenas com o "pincel" e apenas "círculos" quando clicar nos determinados botões

Tags: javascript

Estou construindo um programa simples para desenhar no **canvas** no qual você consegue desenhar um círculo e desenhar com o pincel clicando nos determinados botões `Desenhar círculo` (clicando no **canvas** é desenhado o círculo) e `Pincel` (movendo o mouse por cima do **canvas** é feito o desenho com o pincel):

```js
let btnCircle = document.querySelector('#btn-circle');
let btnBrush = document.querySelector('#btn-brush');
let canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let mouseX, mouseY;

canvas.onmousemove = () => {
    mouseX = event.offsetX;
    mouseY = event.offsetY;
}

btnCircle.onclick = () => {
    canvas.onclick = () => {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(mouseX, mouseY, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.stroke();
    };
}

btnBrush.onclick = () => {
    canvas.onmousemove = () => {
        mouseX = event.offsetX;
        mouseY = event.offsetY;

        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fillRect(mouseX - 10, mouseY - 10, 20, 20);
    };
}
```

```css
canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-circle">Desenhar círculo</button>
<button id="btn-brush">Pincel</button>
<canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid #000;" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Até ai parece que está funcionando bem, mas se, por exemplo, eu clicar no botão `Desenhar círculo` eu consigo desenhar de boa os círculos e se eu clicar no botão `Pincel` eu também consigo desenhar com o pincel, mas clicando nos dois botões acaba acontecendo um problema eu consigo desenhar ao mesmo tempo com o pincel e os círculos o que acaba gerando uma bagunça:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que era para acontecer é quando eu clicar no botão `Desenhar círculo` eu desenho apenas círculos e quando eu clicar no botão `Pincel` eu desenho apenas com o pincel, mas não está acontecendo isso, porque isso está acontecendo? e como eu posso resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta setar uma *flag* (booleana) ou remover o evento `canvas.onclick = () => {` quando for pincel e remover o evento `canvas.onmousemove = () => {` quando for circulo, em programação esse é o *básico*: *o que não é usado deve ser desabilitado ou removido.*

Exemplo removendo os eventos:

```js
let btnCircle = document.querySelector('#btn-circle');
let btnBrush = document.querySelector('#btn-brush');
let canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let mouseX, mouseY;

function circulo()
{
    //Substitui o onmousemove para usar com o circulo
    canvas.onmousemove = () => {
        mouseX = event.offsetX;
        mouseY = event.offsetY;
    };

    //Aplica o click
    canvas.onclick = () => {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(mouseX, mouseY, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.stroke();
    };
}

btnCircle.onclick = circulo;

btnBrush.onclick = () => {
    //Remove o click
    canvas.onclick = null;

    //Substitui o onmousemove para usar com o pincel
    canvas.onmousemove = () => {
        mouseX = event.offsetX;
        mouseY = event.offsetY;

        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fillRect(mouseX - 10, mouseY - 10, 20, 20);
    };
}
```

```css
canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-circle">Desenhar círculo</button>
<button id="btn-brush">Pincel</button>
<canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid #000;" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Ou com *flags* booleanas:

```js
let btnCircle = document.querySelector('#btn-circle');
let btnBrush = document.querySelector('#btn-brush');
let canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let mouseX, mouseY, circulo = false, pincel = false;

canvas.onmousemove = () => {
    mouseX = event.offsetX;
    mouseY = event.offsetY;

    if (pincel) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fillRect(mouseX - 10, mouseY - 10, 20, 20);
    }
}

canvas.onclick = () => {
    if (circulo) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(mouseX, mouseY, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
};

btnCircle.onclick = () => { circulo = true; pincel = false; }
btnBrush.onclick = () => {  circulo = false; pincel = true; }
```

```css
canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-circle">Desenhar círculo</button>
<button id="btn-brush">Pincel</button>
<canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid #000;" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Valeu, @Guilherme Nascimento! verdade eu não tinha pensado nisso ‍♂️